# How to find the minimum value of one variable in two functions using Mathematica?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

How do I find the minimum value which satisfies the two equation below by using *Mathematica*? `d` and `w` in these equations are constant. The only variable is `a`.

```
y=-5 a^3 
y=-a ((5 w d^2)/4 + 5 w d) + (5 w d^2)/2
```

I typed this into *Mathematica* but it is not working

```
MinValue[{-5 a w^2, (5 w d^2)/2 - a (5 w d + (5 w d^2)/4)}, {a}]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, what you want to minimize is the value of `a` subject to the constraint of the equations. If so, the correct syntax is

```
MinValue[{a, -5 a w^2 == (5 w d^2)/2 - 
     a (5 w d + (5 w d^2)/4)}, {a}] // Simplify
```

[image]